# Remove image & link related keybindings in eww

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, eww, shr

I'm using `xah-fly-keys` which provides a few custom keys for easy navigation.

```
u = backward-word
o = forward-word
i = previous-line
...
```

Unfortunately, my keybindings are overshadowed when point is on a visible/hidden link and sometimes even text.

Is there a simple way to force my keybinds over others (`shr-probe-link/save-image`, etc) in eww?

Using `bind-keys`, only `forward-word` works, `i` and `u` fail. Even `v` which normally runs `eww-view-source` switches to `shr-browse-url` when point is on a link.
This is the webpage, it has nested paragraphs inside a tags which highlights the issue: http://www.ultratechnology.com/blog.htm

Below is the code i tried.

```
(bind-keys
 :map image-map
 ("i" .  previous-line)
 ("u" . backward-word)
 ("o" . forward-word)
("v" . eww-view-source) )

(bind-keys 
 :map shr-map
 ("i" .  previous-line)
 ("o" . forward-word)
 ("u" . backward-word)
 ("v" . eww-view-source) )

(bind-keys 
 :map shr-image-map
 ("i" .  previous-line)
 ("o" . forward-word)
 ("u" . backward-word)
 ("v" . eww-view-source) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When over links/regions where your bindings do not work do the following:-

```
C-h k
```

and then press the key whose binding you want to replace. The buffer that appears will show you the existing binding and map and you are then good to go with what you already now.

Comment: Thanks! that helped immensely. Apparently, they all come under eww-link-keymap.